# Modify content inside post before first publish

Tags: functions

I'm trying to make a function (without sucess) that modify a specific part of the post content  before first publish.

```
function modifyOnPost()
{

    add_action( 'the_post', 'modifying' );
    function modifying( $post ) {
    $post->content = str_replace( "original text", "modified text", $post->post_content );
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'modifyOnPost');
```

Nothing happens, not even a error code.

Any help pointing to the right way would be appreciated.

Comment: I would avoid declaring functions inside functions, also neither of those hooks will do what you need them to do, `the_post` actually runs on the frontend at the start of each loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

You should use `save_post` like the following:

```
function modifyOnPost( $post_id ) {
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   //do stuff here before your post is created or updated
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'modifyOnPost' );
```

Read more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

### Update:

To give a deeper solution you could use `wp_update_post( $post, $wp_error );` inside the `modifyOnPost` block to manipulate your post data.